# How to provides autocomplete based on open files in the project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

How to provides autocomplete based on open files in the project in Visual Studio Code?

Unfortunately [All Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete&ssr=false) add-on it's **not a solution** because has many bug and what is most important for me - it breaks autocomplete for php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't expecting it, but this option was introduced natively in VsCode this month. Great job

More info: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5312#issuecomment-724717894